# Bar charts and labels not sorting correctly

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm new to D3.js and I'm trying to display bar chart with check box for sorting, when run the code I'm not checking the check box but the bars are getting sorted by themselves and mix with the labels. I'm not able to recognize where the problem is?

```
<script>
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 200,
    left: 40
},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");


var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


d3.csv("n.csv", type, function (error, data) {

    x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
        return d.Agency_Name;
    }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d.Cost_Variance_M;
    })]);


    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", "-.55em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 8)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Value ($)");

    svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            return x(d.Agency_Name);
        })
        .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.Cost_Variance_M);
        })
        .attr("height", function (d) {
            return height - y(d.Cost_Variance_M);
        });

    svg.selectAll(".text")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "text")
        .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .attr("font-size", "11px")
        .attr("fill", "black");

    d3.select("input").on("change", change);

    var sortTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        d3.select("input").property("checked", true).each(change);
    }, 2000);

    function change() {
        clearTimeout(sortTimeout);


        var x0 = x.domain(data.sort(this.checked ? function (a, b) {
                return b.Cost_Variance_M - a.Cost_Variance_M;
            } : function (a, b) {
                return d3.ascending(a.Agency_Name, b.Agency_Name);
            })
            .map(function (d) {
                return d.Agency_Name;
            }))
            .copy();

        var transition = svg.transition().duration(750),
            delay = function (d, i) {
                return i * 50;
            };

        transition.selectAll(".bar")
            .delay(delay)
            .attr("x", function (d) {
                return x0(d.Agency_Name);
            });

        transition.selectAll(".text")
            .delay(delay)
            .attr("x", function (d) {
                console.log(d.Cost_Variance_M);
                return x0(d.Agency_Name);
            })
            .attr("y", function (d) {
                return height - (d.Cost_Variance_M);
            });

        transition.select(".x.axis")
            .call(xAxis)
            .selectAll("g")
            .delay(delay);
    }
});


function type(d) {
    d.Cost_Variance_M = d.Cost_Variance_M;
    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting the data before it is pumped into the chart

```
data.sort(function(a, b){
 return a.Agency_Name-b.Agency_Name
})
```